# How do draw a shape in the form of a pattern on circle vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am drawing 4 circles. I want to use there circles and plot pattern. For example, on circle with radius as D1I.text, I want to repeat pattern for 60 times spaced evenly, i.e, displaced by angle of 6 deg. At every 6 degree, I want to draw a small rectangle of a fixed shape

```vb
Private Sub Panel2_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel2.Paint

    Dim k As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim centerX, centerY As Integer
    Dim cornerX, cornerY As Integer
    Dim radius As Integer

    centerX = Panel2.Width / 2
    centerY = Panel2.Height / 2
    'Dim i As Integer = N1.Text

    radius = D1A.Text / 2

    cornerX = centerX - radius / 2
    cornerY = centerY - radius / 2
    k.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, cornerX, cornerY, radius, radius)

    'For i = 1 To i Step 1
    '    k.Draw

    'Next

    radius = D1I.Text / 2

    cornerX = centerX - radius / 2
    cornerY = centerY - radius / 2
    k.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, cornerX, cornerY, radius, radius)

    radius = D2A.Text / 2

    cornerX = centerX - radius / 2
    cornerY = centerY - radius / 2
    k.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, cornerX, cornerY, radius, radius)

    radius = D2I.Text / 2

    cornerX = centerX - radius / 2
    cornerY = centerY - radius / 2
    k.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, cornerX, cornerY, radius, radius)
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the question? Note: you cannot divide a string by 2. Convert it to an Integer before division: `radius = CInt(D2A.Text) \ 2`

Comment: Well you can if you have `Option Strict Off`, but you should always have `Option Strict On`. It should be the [default for new projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement#to-set-the-option-strict-default-setting-for-new-projects). Having VB automatically convert "wrong" types can lead to unexpected results and the compiler will not give you any warnings or errors. See: [Option Strict Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

Comment: Thank you for suggestions regarding datatype. I will correct my mistake. I want to draw a rectangle at every 6 degree on circle. how to draw rectangles at specified angles on circles...? This is the question.

Comment: Can you show us a hand-drawn picture of what you're after? ...and some example values for the different TextBoxes would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the coordinate transformations of the `Graphics` object. These transformations move and rotate the coordinate grid around. The drawing commands draw relative to this grid.

I simplified the method a bit. I assume (because we are missing your specification) that `D1I` is the diameter of an inner circle and `D1A` the diameter of an outer circle of a watch and that we want to draw 60 tick marks between the two circles.

First let's write a helper method for drawing circles:

```vb
Private Sub DrawCircle(g As Graphics, pen As Pen, centerX As Integer, centerY As Integer, radius As Integer)
    g.DrawEllipse(pen, centerX - radius, centerY - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius)
End Sub
```

Then to the main paint method:

```vb
Private Sub Panel2_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel2.Paint
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

    Dim radius1I As Integer = CInt(D1I.Text) \ 2
    Dim radius1A As Integer = CInt(D1A.Text) \ 2

    Dim centerX As Integer = Panel2.Width \ 2
    Dim centerY As Integer = Panel2.Height \ 2

    DrawCircle(g, Pens.Black, centerX, centerY, radius1I)
    DrawCircle(g, Pens.Black, centerX, centerY, radius1A)


    ' Move the coordinate origin to the center
    g.TranslateTransform(centerX, centerY)

    Dim tickWidth As Integer = 8
    Dim tickMark As New Rectangle(radius1I, -tickWidth \ 2, radius1A - radius1I, tickWidth)
    For i = 0 To 59
        g.RotateTransform(6)
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, tickMark)
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that I am using the integer division `\` which returns an integer.

Since we rotate the coordinate system, we can always draw a horizontal rectangle:

```
   |                   -----radius1A -->
   |                        +-----------+   y = - tickWidth \ 2
---o-------------radius1I-->| tick mark |
   |                        +-----------+   y = + tickWidth \ 2
```

Result with the diameters 300 and 350:

[image]